# Error while create new react-native project by using expo while running expo init myapp

Tags: react-native, expo

any help[Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank-typescript --dry-run".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MA1G.png)

any help thanks.

while running npm pack expo-template-blank-typescript --dry-run

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uwxx.png)

notice that using nvm node -v16.0.0 , creating angular 11 , reactjs project with no problem , i'm new with react-native

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're having trouble connecting to npm. if you run `npm pack expo-template-blank-typescript --dry-run` what happens?

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote `npm pack expo-template-blank-typescript --dry-run` in my vscode terminal

[it shows me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzMvG.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).